# Cannot modify UI of viewControllers added from storyboard to PageViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller

I have a PageViewController, in which I want to add some "cards"(ViewController). Every card will take one page. And ViewController of card need to instantiated from storyboard since I've already set some UIOutlet.

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    //Get info of the former page
    ZDMainCardsViewController *formerVC = (ZDMainCardsViewController *)viewController;
    //Use a property to mark VC's number
    NSInteger formerIndex = formerVC.cardIndex;

    //Init from Storyboard
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"ZDMain" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    UIViewController *cardsVC = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ZDMainCardsCollectionViewController"];

    //Set this VC
    ZDMainCardsViewController *thisVC = (ZDMainCardsViewController *)cardsVC;

    //Fill data according to VC's number.
    //In the beginning I tried to do this in viewDidLoad by using self.cardIndex
    //That turns to be useless, and I add a method to do so
    //Though, it's useless too
    [thisVC loadNextCard:formerIndex];
    return thisVC;
}
```

Code and my aim is showed above. Now the result is every card is the same. Breakpoints show that VC.cardIndex never changes. In the loadNextCard method, `self.oneLabel.text = data` ran without a effect.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to access ViewController's outlets before they are initialized.
View Controller's view is lazily loaded when you *present* this view controller or access its `view` property.

Try checking `viewController.isViewLoaded` property before accessing its outlets and call `[viewController loadView]` or simply `[viewController view]` if needed

> VC.cardIndex never changes

May you have forgotten to increment your index?

```
[thisVC loadNextCard:formerIndex + 1];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Alexey! `[viewController view]` does work! But I don't understand since I'm trying to reuse the VC comes from SB, how could it not be in memory before I use `[viewController view]`?

Comment: Storyboard is basically the same as xib, and it's compiled to nib-s when you build your project. When you instantiate a view controller, it just allocates the ViewController and sets its nibName/bundle properties to lazily load later, when the *view* property is accessed.